# Julia: Collapsing DataFrame by multiple values retaining additional variables

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have some data that has duplicate fields with the exception of a single field which I would like to join. In the data everything but the `report` should stay the same on each day and each company. Companies can file multiple reports on the same day.

I can join using the following code but I am losing the variables which are not in my `by` function. Any suggestions?

#### Mock Data

```
using DataFrames

# Number of observations
n = 100
words = split("the wigdet drop air flat fall fling flap freeze flop tool fox", " ")
df = DataFrame(day = cumsum(rand(0:1, n)), company = rand(0:3, n), 
  report = [join(rand(words, rand(1:5, 1)[1]), " ") for i in 1:n])

x = df[:, [:day, :company]]

# Number of variables which are identical for each day/company.
nv = 100
for i in 1:nv
    df[:, Symbol("v" * string(i))] = ""
end

for i in 1:size(x, 1),j in 1:nv
    df[(df.day .== x[i,1]) .& (df.company .== x[i,2]), Symbol("v" * string(j))] = 
    join(rand('a':'z', 3), "")
end
```

#### Collapsed data

```
outdf = by(df, [:company, :day]) do sub
  t = DataFrame(fullreport = join(sub.report, "\n(Joined)\n"))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some minor tweaks in your data preparation code:

```
using DataFrames

# Number of observations
n = 100
words = split("the wigdet drop air flat fall fling flap freeze flop tool fox", " ")
df = DataFrame(day = cumsum(rand(0:1, n)), company = rand(0:3, n), 
  report = [join(rand(words, rand(1:5, 1)[1]), " ") for i in 1:n])

x = df[:, [:day, :company]]

# Number of variables which are identical for each day/company.
nv = 100
for i in 1:nv
    df[:, Symbol("v", i)] .= ""
end

for i in 1:size(x, 1), j in 1:nv
    df[(df.day .== x[i,1]) .& (df.company .== x[i,2]), Symbol("v", j)] .= join(rand('a':'z', 3), "")
end
```

and here is `by` that keeps all other variables (assuming they are constant per group, this code should be efficient even for relatively large data):

```
outdf = by(df, [:company, :day]) do sub
    merge((fullreport = join(sub.report, "\n(Joined)\n"),),
          copy(sub[1, Not([:company, :day, :report])]))
end
```

I put the `fullreport` variable as a first one.

Here is the code that would keep all rows from the original data frame:

```
outdf = by(df, [:company, :day]) do sub
    insertcols!(select(sub, Not([:company, :day, :report])), 1,
                fullreport = join(sub.report, "\n(Joined)\n"))
end
```

and now you can e.g. check that `unique(outdf)` produces the same data frame as the one that was generated by the fist `by`.

(in the codes above I dropped also `:report` variable as I guess you did not want it in the result - right?)